# Distinguish between `\tkzGetFirstPoint` and `\tkzGetSecondPoint`

Tags: tkz-euclide

Repeatedly I am encountering the following problem:

I have some code in `tkz-euclide` working fine. For example it could be

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){M}
\tkzDefPoint(1,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(2,1){B}
\tkzInterLC(A,B)(M,A)\tkzGetFirstPoint{C}
\tkzDefTriangleCenter[circum](A,M,C)\tkzGetPoint{U}
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,M,U)
\tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C,M,U)
\tkzDrawCircle(U,A)
\tkzDrawCircle(M,A)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that it gives a different (wrong) picture, if
`\tkzGetFirstPoint{C}` is replaced by `\tkzGetSecondPoint{C}`. (In the latter case `C` should be the same as `A`, which would return in an error. In practice it seems that due to rounding effects `C` is nearby `A`, which results in a very big circumcircle of `(A,M,C)`.

But every now and then (maybe with an update in some package) the `FirstPoint` and `SecondPoint` can interchange their meaning and I have to adapt dozens of my pictures.

How can this be avoided? I know that there is an alternative construction by reflecting `A` with respect to the perpendicular line to `AB` through `M`. However this is much more complicated.

Comment: What is your version of tkz-euclide?

Answer (score 1):

With the version 4.03 and 4.05

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){M}
\tkzDefPoint(1,0){A}
\tkzDefPoint(2,1){B}
\tkzInterLC[common=A](A,B)(M,A)\tkzGetFirstPoint{C}
\tkzDefTriangleCenter[circum](A,M,C)\tkzGetPoint{U}
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C,M,U)
\tkzDrawCircles(U,A M,A)
\tkzLabelPoints(A,B,C,M,U)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have improved the possibility to choose the intersection points with (Line-Circle) (Circle-Circle) and (Tangent-Circle).

Version 4.03 still has some flaws that's why I tried to find a correct way to choose the points in all cases.

Line-Circle : you have several possibilities

1. No common point : I created a test (``newif ...`) to see if the intersection was empty.
2. Only one point : no problem to choose.
3. The line goes through the center. You can use the option `near`. `tkzFirstPoint` is assigned to the point closest to the first point that defines the line. Here the first point is `A` but if you want you can write `(B,A)`.
4. Two points but you know a point (here `A`) this is the `common` point. Automatically the second point of the intersection is assigned to `tkzFirstPoint`.
5. General case : The macro compares the angles `(tkzFirstPoint,tkzSecondPoint,O)` and `(tkzSecondPoint, tkzFirstPoint,O)` with `O` center of the circle. The smallest angle determines `tkzFirstPoint`. In fact one of the angles is counterclockwise and the other clockwise.
   I will finish in the next days the new version 4.05 with more explanations and examples as well as a small document only about intersections and how to test to avoid errors.

[image]

Comment: It's possible also to test some lengths `(\ifdim ...)` in order to choose the points. I will give some examples in the documentation